# Spring Integration http inbound gateway not working when FeignClient instance wired to any Config Class which annotated @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, feign

It's a Spring Cloud microservice web app built by SpringBoot. We are using Kafka 0.10.1, according to the compatibility matrix, this pom.xml file describes the dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.yonyou.occ</groupId>
    <artifactId>davcointegration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myintegration</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <oracle.version>11.1.0.7.0</oracle.version>
        <iuap.modules.version>3.1.0-RELEASE</iuap.modules.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${oracle.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

The code works:

```
                .from(Http.inboundGateway("goods/{operation}")
                        .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                        .requestPayloadType(String.class)
                        .headerExpression(MessageHeaderName.OPERATION, "#pathVariables.operation"))
//......
```

It still works when @EnableFeignClients add to Spring Boot Application entry.
But once the @FeignClient instance wired to(by @Autowired) any config Class(@Configuration), it's not working.
I have checked http://myproject/mappings (The request mappings info provided by Spring boot), mappings "/goods/**" disappeared.

**It's a simple project that explains this problem:** https://github.com/Princelo/demoForSiAndFeignProblem/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/config/AnyConfig.java

Comment: I don't think you've described the problem well enough.

Comment: Some GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2752 for more info and for tracking the fix.

Meanwhile as a workaround I suggest to have a `@Lazy` whenever you try to inject Feign client interfaces.

The problem that `FeignClientFactoryBean` initiate a new child `ApplicationContext` for each Feign cleint and calls a `ContextRefreshedEvent` for them too early. The `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` doesn't check for the context of the event and marks itself initialized wrong way, missing the scan for appropriate HTTP components.